# Enabling Intel Integrated Graphics on CLEVO P775TM1-G for use as QEMU pass-through gpu

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, intel-graphics, gpu-passthrough

I'm wondering if it's possible to use my laptops i9-9900K's integrated gpu as a pass-through GPU for QEMU.

The display in this laptop is directly connected to a RTX 2080, and is the only VGA device that shows up when running:

```
> lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU104BM [GeForce RTX 2080 Mobile] (rev a1)
```

I'm not familiar with how integrated graphic cards are interacted with (via PCI, memory mapping, gpu specific instructions etc). If it's over the PCI bus, it could possible that it's simply not hooked up to it?

Answer (score 0):

Run `lspci -nnk` and inspect the output. Particularly, you want to pay attention to the first two digits in scheme `xx:xx.x`. That is the IOMMU group of that PCI-e device.

My understanding is that if your GPU has its own group, then you might have a chance of passing it through successfully. If not, then it becomes a pain-in-the-neck. There are some workarounds, but they seem to involve security and stability risks.

https://www.reddit.com/r/VFIO/comments/bvif8d/official_reason_why_acs_override_patch_is_not_in/

https://www.reddit.com/r/VFIO/comments/bvif8d/official_reason_why_acs_override_patch_is_not_in/eppfcf1/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3